# Access javascript variable outside post function

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I know this has been asked a million times, but all I see is people explaining scope and no one explains a solution.

In this case HOW do I get alert to show the value of comment_count rather than undefined.

```
 var comment_count;
 $.post( "<?=site_url('comments/ajax_get_comment_count');?>",{tags:[aData[7],'BWQ']}, function( data ) {

  comment_count = data;

  });

  alert(comment_count);
```

Comment: If you know there's a lot of questions (and answers) for this question, why not read them?

Comment: @nit, I would suggest you read my question again. You will see that I can only find explanations for for how scope works, but no examples of how to use a variable outside a $.post function.

Comment: Then it simply seems you're not that good at reading answers.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need something like that:

```
 var comment_count;

function controller(){


    return {
        setValue:function(_val,data){
           _val = data;
            this.fireValue(_val)
        },
        fireValue:function(_val){
            alert(_val)   
        }
    }

}

$.post("<?=site_url('comments/ajax_get_comment_count');?>", {tags: [aData[7], 'BWQ']}, function (data) {

    controller.setValue(comment_count,data)

});
```

Comment: That's not what was asked

Comment: You can try module pattern of javascript or you must explain what you asked specificly better!